# Function that displays a text for the equation of a linear model

Tags: r, text, lm

I'd like to take the following "eq" function and improve it in two ways:

1. So it can run for any number of coefficients
2. So it will make the variables display without the matrix portion i.e. like this:

   y == 0.29 + 0.18 * "b" + 0.4 * "c"

my code:

```
x=data.frame(runif(12),rep(c('a','b','c'),4))
lm3=lm(x[,1]~x[,2])
eq=function(c){
bquote( y == .(c[1]) + .(c[2]) * .(names(c)[2])
        + .(c[3]) * .(names(c)[3])) }
c=summary(lm3)$coefficients
c=round(c[,1], digits = 2)
c=summary(lm3)$coefficients
c=round(c[,1], digits = 2)

    > eq(c)
    y == 0.29 + 0.18 * "x[, 2]b" + 0.4 * "x[, 2]c"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using some `paste` and `parse`

#### Edit

I was trying originally to deal with the possibility of no intercept, but it got too confusing with the possibility of factor/non-factor variables, so this just assumes the intercept.

```
eq <- function(fit, digits=2) {
    vnames <- attr(terms(fit), 'term.labels')
    x <- round(coef(fit), digits)
    ns <- Vectorize(gsub)(vnames, '', names(x), fixed=TRUE)[-1]  # remove intercept
    xx <- as.vector(x)
    vars <- c(xx[1], paste(xx[-1], ns, sep="*"))
    parse(text=paste0("y == ", paste(vars, collapse=" + ")))
}

## data
x <- data.frame(runif(12),rep(c('a','b','c'),4))
lm3 <- lm(x[,1]~x[,2])

eq(lm3, 2)
# expression(y == 0.35 + 0.21*b + 0.26*c)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know how to get rid of the "expression" portion?

Comment: what are you trying to do with the result?  I figured you wanted an expression since yours is returning a "call" with the double "=" signs?  In this form, if you want to add it as a label to a graph, you can just do, `plot(1, type="n"); text(1, eq(lm3, 2))` for example

Comment: However, if you just want text output, remove the `parse(text=` altogether and you will just get a string.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. I was going to output it but I see the expression is useful for graphing. It is probably more useful to future people in this form...